# WMS feed displays in ArcCatalog 9.3 but not in ArcMap 9.3

Tags: arcgis-10.1, wms, mapserver, arcgis-9.3

I am facing a very very weird behaviour. We used to work with a WMS feed in ArcGIS 9.3 and, since a few weeks, we are no longer able to display it.

The providers of the feed informed us that they have "made some changes" in the feed, which might cause the problem. They have now reverted some of the changes and the behavior is as follows:

**ArcCatalog 9.3**: the WMS sublayers can be displayed
**ArcMap 9.3**: the WMS sublayers appear in the TOC but the data view remains "white and empty" (no error message is displayed)
**ArcCatalog 10.1**: the WMS sublayers can be displayed
**ArcMap 10.1**: the WMS sublayers can be displayed

As anyone been facing something like this? Do you have any idea how I can monitor it or what can cause this incompatibility in 9.3? I believe that the server should send back the WMS tiles along with an XML file. Anyone knows where this XML file would be stored by ArcGIS?

The WMS feed is served with MapServer 6.3

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: A variant of this question has also been posted here: forums.arcgis.com/threads/79842-Where-does-ArcGIS-temporarily-store-the-WMS-tiles But no success so far...

Comment: what version of WMS are you using? can you try changing the version to 1.0.0 or 1.1.0 and seeing if that changes anything?

Comment: I am not the provider of the WMS feed so I cannot influence its configuration. It is supposed to support 1.1.0, 1.1.1 and 1.1.3

Comment: What version are you asking for in ArcCatlog. You can change that in ArcCatalog and see if it makes any difference

Comment: I have tried all of them... no difference. The provider of the WMS have informed me that it should NOT work wirh 1.0.0 but that it _should_ work with the other versions

Comment: When all else fails: dump the requests made from ArcMap 9.3 to the WMS feed and then compare them against working ones. You can use wireshark or an http proxy to capture the requests.

Comment: Thanks, I haved captured everything with Fiddler and sent the log files to ESRI. Waiting for their answer and will keep you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, nobody at ESRI was able to reproduce or to explain the problem. I would then assume it rather has to do with our internal setup (network?) but it's still a really weird behavior.